# nginx ETag invalidation

Tags: http, nginx, browser-cache, cache-control, etag

I'm caching static resources using the following code in my `nginx.conf`:

```
http {
    ...
    gzip on;
    gzip_types *;
    gzip_vary on;
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location /static {
            alias /opt/static_root;
            expires max;
        }
    }
}
```

This is sufficient to set the following http headers:

```
$ curl -I example.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css
Content-Length: 97874
Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 18:30:33 GMT
ETag: "58333d49-17e52"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
```

However, even though the `Last-Modified` date is later than the cached version the browser has, I'm still seeing the old version of the file (tested on Firefox 50.0 and Chrome  54.0.2840.98).

How can I invalidate the ETag so that whenever I deploy diffs to my static files, the browser understands to reload them?

I have tried `nginx -s reload`, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETags are used when a client makes a Conditional Request to revalidate an expired resource. But in your case the resource won't expire until 2037! The browser will continue to serve the resource from its cache until then without ever checking with the server. That's what you told it to with your `Expires` header.

Typically if you're going to do far-future expires like that you have to version the resource by changing the name. Or you can change the `Expires` to something shorter, in which case the `ETags` will be used when the client tries to revalidate.

Comment: Ok, so there is currently no mechanism to (say) send the sha1 hash every request to decide whether to re-download an asset, and only download when the hash has changed?

Comment: @NickThompson: Sure, you can do that by setting the resource to expire immediately. In that case the browser will send the appropriate headers for a conditional request, and the server will use the ETag to determine whether the resource has changed or not. (FYI, it [looks like](http://serverfault.com/a/690374) nginx does not use hashes to determine ETags.)